# How to use SQL Server Reporting Services reports with visual basic 6.0

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, vb6, crystal-reports, reporting

We have an application in VB6 where reports are created with Crystal Reports 8.5
We want to migrate the reports to SSRS, but the app will remain in VB6 for some time. 
I have searched a way to print e report in SSRS from vb6 with no luch.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Export report output to Pdf format then print the pfd output using vb6.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838937/exporting-pdf-in-reporting-services) will export ssrs report output to the pdf format using